# Spring with Hibernate annotation based

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am looking at Spring documentation to learn Spring integration with Hibernate using annotation based spring configuration.

The documentation link is [here.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate)

Now the docs tell about how to configure Spring with Hibernate using xml files and there is no where mentioned how to use annotations for integrating Spring and Hibernate.

Please help me where can I find the explanation on Spring with Hibernate integration using annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the required annotations here - [Annotations used for configuring DAO or Repository classes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/dao.html#dao-annotations)

Here is a good example for using Spring with Hibernate -  [Spring Hibernate Integration Using Annotations](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-session-factory-annotation.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-dao-example/

I'm not sure if I should downvote you - you could easily find it on your own.
Ok, maybe it is not exactly Spring + Hibernate, but it really does not matter.

Comment: I am looking for information from Spring official documentation. Also you have given link for Hibernate annotations, my question is on Spring with Hibernate, so this does not answer my question.